# Can't initiate next dev server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to start a Next.js server running `npx next dev` but in the browser the following error is shown:

[next error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZz46.png)

[browser console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbwvU.png)

Does someone know what this error is?

Already tried delete `node_modules` and `package.json` and reinstall packages.